# Is it possible to get the Area 51 ads on my site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, area-51, advertising

On sites such as Super User is it possible that someone could make something like the Area 51 ads on the right hand side to use on my own site.

Also to that if you can could you have one for sites in the definition phase?

Comment: What an interesting idea! Are there any banner ads to promote the sites? If not, why not?

Comment: @Pekka Yesy that was what I was thinking

Comment: @Pekka I second the motion

Comment: Hopefully there's no practical reason why not :)

Comment: @Tim smart thinking

Comment: @Tim becuase you are a mod now (well done :)) can you try to make this happen please :((

Comment: @Benny - I don't have much influence over what does and doesn't get implemented, other than adding my voice to the collective "Yeah, that would be a good idea" pool.

Comment: +1 First silver badge for you!

Comment: @Jon Seigel Thanks I will party all night tonight

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is now!

To embed the [Jewish life and learning proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning), for example, you can use either of the following <strike>two</strike> three techniques:

---

**EDIT**: The preferred embed technique is to link to the ad png:

**image**

```
<a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning"><img src="http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/22435.png" width="220" height="250" alt="Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Jewish life and learning" /></a>
```

*Example*:

[image]

---

**iframe**

```
<iframe src="http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/22435" height="250" width="220" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**script**

```
<script src="http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/22435/js"></script>
```

Comment: @Emmett - Were these just created?  I hope I wasn't missing something obvious all along?  Thanks!  Can we put this information in the FAQ or a section about advertising?  Thanks again.  +1

Comment: @jmort253, yes, this is new. (:

Comment: @Emmett: Can you modify it to include a referral code?

Comment: You all work fast.  This is awesome!

Comment: @Jan Done. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81099/can-we-please-have-referrer-links-in-area-51-proposal-ads/81262#81262

Comment: @Emmett Is it possable to have a banner ad for it?

Answer (score 3):

While it's true that there are no pre-canned Area51 banner code generators, it is possible to use the code from the Area51 ads themselves.

Below is the code that you can place in an IFRAME for the Running Q&A Banner Ad:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            #a51-ad { background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat bottom center; }
            #a51-ad, #a51-ad a { display:block; height: 250px; width: 220px; text-decoration: none;          }
            #a51-ad table { position: relative; top: 55px; }
            #a51-ad-title-row { height: 95px; }
            #a51-ad-title { padding: 0 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Impact,'Futura-CondensedExtraBold',sans-serif; color: #FBF9E2; text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
              width: 220px; vertical-align: middle; }
            #a51-ad-perc { padding:3px; text-align: center; color: white; font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }
            #a51-ad .a51-ad-len-0 { font-size: 32px; }
            #a51-ad .a51-ad-len-1 { font-size: 28px; line-height: 32px; }
            #a51-ad .a51-ad-len-2 { font-size: 24px; line-height: 28px; }
        </style>
        <div id="a51-ad" style="float:right;">
            <a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6530/running?commit=1">
                <table>
                    <tbody><tr id="a51-ad-title-row"><td id="a51-ad-title" class="a51-ad-len-0">Running Q&amp;A</td></tr>
                        <tr><td id="a51-ad-perc">37% committed</td></tr>
                    </tbody></table>        
            </a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/js?id=a51-ad-container"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can take all of the code within the body tags and place them in the appropriate section on your website.

More information, as well as a demo, can be found in this post titled [How To Use Stack Exchange Area51 Advertisements](http://blog.opensourceopportunities.com/2011/02/how-to-use-stack-exchange.html).

**DISCLAIMER**:  I do not know if this violates any terms of services of using Stack Exchange.  My thought is that as long as the advertisements aren't modified, it should be okay to use them to **help promote this network**.  I'm not a legal expert, so this is just my opinion.  In addition to instructing you on how to use Area51 advertisements on your site, the steps I've provided to accomplish this also serve as entertainment value.

Here is a section from the Terms and Conditions on "fair use":

> Trademark and Copyright
>
> The logos associated with Stack Overflow Inc. and any Stack Exchange site are a trademark. The purpose of trademark law is to prevent consumers from being misled as to the origin of a product. So if you were making a product, and you used a Stack Exchange name or logo in your product (or in its advertising) in such a way that would mislead someone into thinking that your product was owned by, operated by, endorsed by, or in any way part of Stack Overflow Inc., you would be violating the trademark and this would not be legal.
>
> Our logo images and site names are copyrighted. Any content on the Stack Exchange Network not contributed by users is copyrighted. Copyright is different than trademark. Ordinarily you couldn't copy it. But if you were writing a news story or blog post about a Stack Exchange site, reproducing the logo image would almost certainly be considered "fair use" and allowed under trademark law because you were not using it "in trade."

**UPDATE:** More information from the Terms and Conditions:

> Use of Our Name or Logo in Advertising
>
> - Do use the most current logo where applicable and permitted.
> - Do use the proper name for our company, product, or service (see "Proper use of the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Name" below).
> - Do not use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Overflow Inc.
> - Do not use our name or logo in a way that might imply a false sense of partnership or endorsement with your product.
> - Do not use any name or logo that is similar to or might be confused with our name or logo.
> - Do not distort or alter our logo in any way.
> - Do not use our logo in a way that confuses our brand with another brand.
> - Do not use any other artwork from our network without explicit permission.

Here it is in black and white.  Don't alter the logo without permission.  Don't use the logo without permission.  However, in the fair use section, it says it's okay to use logos from Stack Exchange when talking about Stack Exchange.  This is very confusing.

***If you want to use any of the steps I have provided to create Stack Exchange ads, I strongly suggest you obtain written permission from the owners of this site.  You may email them at team@stackoverflow.com.***

Comment: What about runs that are at the start?

Comment: You mean those that are in Beta?  If you mean the ones in Beta, then in that case you may need to modify the Anchor Tag hyperlink to point to the Beta and modify the innerHTML to represent the name of the Q&A site.  Commit percentage would of course be 100%.  I don't know if this is legal though and whether or not that will violate any terms of conditions.  I'd suggest we see if maybe Jeff Atwood has anything to say about this before investing too much time in this.

Comment: @Benny - The question you need to answer -- if modifying the link of the ad to point to a Public Beta SE site -- is whether or not that constitutes "fair use" or if the Stack Exchange operators would consider you using that "in trade".

Comment: I mean the definition phase with how many users have signed up e.g the Sports one please.

Comment: Just like with BETA phase, you would have to find the link and modify the ad.  Put this link http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports in the href and change `Running Q&A` to `Sports Q&A` and then put that code on your Web Server.  Again, see the disclaimer in my answer.