# Can we please have referrer links in Area 51 proposal ads?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, advertising

I saw we can now have [Area 51 proposal ads to put on our sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76778/is-it-possible-to-get-the-area-51-ads-on-my-site). **That's awesome.**

Now, can we please also have the option to tack on our referrer code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. A proposal's embed script (with referral code) is now accessible from its "Share This" popup, which is shown once you've followed or committed to a proposal:

[image: screenshot of new embed ui]

Comment: I love you people!!

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to include the script version in that dialog as well? The iframe version doesn't work in WordPress blogs.

Comment: @Alex It's already possible. Just add `?referrer=foo` to the script src. I suppose we should include the script version in the popup too so that's more clear..

Comment: @Emmett: If you wouldn't mind. :)

Comment: @Alex The popup includes the script version as well now.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some javascript to referrify the link of the `a51-ad` object in that iframe.