# Show Area51 ads in the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, area-51, advertising, sidebar

We have seen several different types of ads in the sidebar of the sites. [We also have Area 51 ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76778/is-it-possible-to-get-the-area-51-ads-on-my-site):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Espionage]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/54104.png))</sub>

These ads are *not* shown in the sidebars.

**What would you say of adding these to the sidebars as well?**

---

<sup>As we're getting some crap on Area 51 as well, perhaps there should be some follower amount threshold before the ad to appear in a sidebar, but that's a detail.</sup>

<sup>Also, as Sha Wiz Dow Ard says in the comments, the engine can track the user's tags to see in what he's interested. In addition to that, the engine could show more Technology proposals on Technology websites, and the same goes for other categories.</sup>

Comment: Nice suggestion, it can analyze the user's tags to decide which site suggestions are likely to interest him/her.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd good idea, I added that!

Answer (score 12):

I think it would be a stupid idea *not* to, it opens peoples eyes up to what else SO has to offer, and can help get that new community the evangelists it needs to get off the ground who may never have know others were even trying to set it up

Answer (score 1):

Graduated sites can add specific Area-51 ads to their rotations by nominating them (and voting them up) on meta posts such as [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1414/472).  The voting ensures a basic level of community support for the ad.  We have an Area-51 ad in our rotation on Mi Yodeya because of that post.  Check your meta for the post from the community team.

Comment: Community ads are not a good place for this, because (a) proposals are added the year round while community-ads posts are mostly active during December/January and (b) proposals can get closed and then the old community-ad is still active. So I really don't think it's a good idea to add Area51-ads to community-ads posts.

Comment: Also, graduated sites' ads are shown in the sidebar, without having to pass through the community-ads post. So why not have the same for Area51 proposed sites?

Comment: At last, these Area 51 ads shouldn't be allowed as community-ad: they're not hosted on imgur, whilst that is a requirement. You _should not_ host an Area 51 ad on imgur, since it wouldn't update with the current information anymore.

Comment: Re "why not?", for the reason you give in the question: not all proposals merit advancement.  If human intervention is necessary to vet the proposals anyway, you may as well use the existing mechanism.  (Ads can be added and removed during the year AFAIK.)  BTW, we don't host our Area-51 ad on imgur; check the markdown for that ad in the linked post.  We worked with the community team on that.

Comment: Exactly, that is the problem: community-ads should be hosted on imgur, it's in the requirements list. Community-ads can be added and removed during the year, but the post is mostly active around the turn of the year, so adding an add in July won't have much effect (especially not on smaller sites). For the craps proposals, we can have a threshold of say 3 or 5 followers before a proposal gets advertised for.

Comment: It was in the requirements list [of 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93312/205264) already.

Comment: I tried this once and got a lot of downvotes, but I've also known people who got upvotes...