# What's the best way to create a community ad for a beta site?

Tags: discussion, advertising

There are [premade ads for Area51 proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76778/is-it-possible-to-get-the-area-51-ads-on-my-site), and those do still exist for sites in beta, but they still call it a "new site proposal" and prominently say "AREA 51":

[image: area 51 proposal ad]

Are there any premade images that more clearly convey that the site in fact isn't just a proposal, it already exists?

I'm imagining something with the blue and white beta colors, maybe the placeholder logo, probably not mentioning area 51:

[image: fake ad]

Comment: Well, hot questions on beta sites do get automatic ad sometimes, I just saw this for example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvtum.png

Comment: If I recall, there's a feature request ... somewhere (I think) to make the routes that generate those ads produce something a little saner for sites that made it beyond the proposal stage. As with many things (especially where touching Area 51 is concerned), we haven't quite gotten around to it yet.

Answer (score 4):

Draw it yourself over some liberally licensed beautiful stock image.

[image: Space Exploration SE]
Author: [Tildal Wave](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/365/168)

[image: Community Ad #2]
Author: [Undo](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/366/168)

---

In response to a comment on actually getting the images with stunning visual effects and permissive licenses, and taking cue from the SE site dedicated to [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) one finds this Q: [Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-royalty-free-stock-images).

Comment: Could you add something about places to look for liberally-licensed beautiful stock images?

Comment: I'm not really sure about gardening and landscaping, but NASA has got 90k+ images [here](http://www.dvidshub.net/search/?filter[unit]=NASA&filter[type]=image&sort=date). Most popular search engines also provide image search.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - fixed.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update!