# Can I advertise Stack Exchange sites on my web site?

Tags: feature-request, support, advertising

We have many cross-site advertisements on the Stack Exchange network, highlighting questions, an Area51 proposed sites, and of course the per-site [community promition ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) etc.  An example:

[image]

Is there any way to post such advertisements on my own site?  Of course, ideally, I would love to earn revenue from such things, but even in the absence of the option for earning revenue, I would love the opportunity to help promote my favorite/most relevant SE sites on my blog.

Is such an advertising channel available?  If not, I guess this is a feature request. :)

*EDIT:* I've found that it's simple to extract the relevant JS snippet to produce the same ads as found on the various sites, but for this to be relevant to me, I would need a) permission to do so from SE, and b) the ability to display ads/questions only from the site(s) I choose, rather than from the entire SE network.

Comment: [Area 51 proposals are possible to host on your own website](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76778/is-it-possible-to-get-the-area-51-ads-on-my-site), not sure about the randomly selected hot questions though.